# What happens when two nitrates react with each other?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I have to determine the products of the ammonium nitrate and copper nitrate. Is the below reaction correct?

$$\ce{NH4NO3 + Cu(NO3)2 -> Cu(NH3)4(NO3)2}$$

(ammonium nitrate + copper nitrate → tetrammine copper(ii) nitrate)

Also, what would be the products of the other two reactions below:

- copper nitrate + lead nitrate
- lead nitrate + ammonium nitrate

Basically, what happens when you react any two nitrates?

Comment: Your equation doesn't balance so it can't be right. Also what happens to the hydrogen ions released from the ammonium ions when they become ammonia ligands.